# How to get ArrayBuffer from audio track?

Tags: javascript, audio, web-audio-api

I need to join multiples audio tracks in js and I need to get a ArrayBuffer to do audioContext.decodeAudioData(). How can I do this?

that's the code :

```
 let tracks = []
  streamsAudio.forEach((track) => {
    let elem = document.createElement('audio')
    elem.srcObject = track.src
    elem.play()

    tracks.push(track.src.getAudioTracks()[0])
  })


 const ac = new AudioContext();
 
ac.decodeAudioData(ArrayBuffer, function(data) {
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear why you need an `ArrayBuffer` so you can decode the
data.  The audio tag can already decode the audio for you.

One way is to attach your `audio` element to a
[`MediaElementAudioSourceNode`](https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#mediaelementaudiosourcenode). Connect
this to `ScriptProcessorNode` or `AudioWorkletNode` to get the data
from the individual tracks.  A quick sketch (untested):

```
// Make elem global instead of local for this to work.  Then
let s = new MediaElementAudiouSourceNode(ac, {mediaElement: elem});
// 8192 is just an example.  You could choose other values
let spn = ac.createScriptProcessorNode(8192, <number of channels>, 0);
spn.onaudioprocess = (e) => {
  let input = e.inputBuffer;
  for (let k = 0; k < input.length; ++k) {
    let channel = input.getChannelData(k);
    // channel has one channel from the tracks.  Process it as you see
    // fit.
  }
}

s.connect(spn).connect(ac.destination);
```

You will have to determine the number of channels for the script
processor.  It may not be the same as the the number of tracks if a
track contains, say, stereo audio.

Comment: What would be the chanlels?

Comment: Let's say you have two tracks. Each track consists of a stereo audio clip.  Then there are 4 channels, two from each track.  I don't think it's well specified how all the channels in each track get mapped to the input of the ScriptProcessorNode.  But the final result from the ScriptProcessor would be, roughly, what you would get if you did have the ArrayBuffer to send to decodeAudioData